# angular ng-src and data-src together not work

Tags: html, angularjs

When ng-src and data-src use together, it don't work, like that:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
    <img ng-src="{{userpic}}" data-src="{{userpic}}" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainController', ['$scope',

function ($scope) {
    $scope.userpic = 'http://placehold.it/350x150';
}]);
```

If you skip data-src="{{userpic}}", it work agian, I don't know why.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mKWVh/

Comment: I believe [`ng-src` description](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) explains everything quite clear.  Did you read it?

Comment: Why do you need to add both?

Comment: Just curiosity why can't using together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to add `data-src` attribute, if you want the directive to comply with some IE version then you can simply use `data-ng-src="{{userpic}}`

```
<div ng-app="suncake" ng-controller="MainController">
    <img data-ng-src="{{userpic}}" width="69" height="69" />
</div>
```